# Color Transition to layout fro Bottom to top Gradually

Tags: android, view

I want to give progress of a process differently instead of seekbar i want color my activity from bottom to top.if it reaches top means process complete. How can i achieve this.

i tried creating a view on layout and increasing height of view gradually according to process progress but problem is its is showing at a time not gradually

```
View line = new View(this);
    line.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#22FF6666"));
     RelativeLayout.LayoutParams rLParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,i*10);
             rLParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM, -1);
             rMain.addView(line,rLParams);
```

Comment: u dont u try to increase the height of the view?

Comment: use a ClipDrawable as a background of your view/layout

Comment: i got solution using handler :)

Comment: @user3201189 handler has little to do with your problem

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom animation that changes height.

```
public class HeightAnimation extends Animation {

    private View view;
    private int oldValue,newValue;

    public HeightAnimation(View view,int oldValue,int newValue) {
        this.view=view;
            this.old=oldValue;
            this.newValue=newValue;
        setDuration(300);
    }

    @Override
    protected void applyTransformation(float interpolatedTime, Transformation t) {
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams rLParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,(int)(oldValue+(newValue-oldValue)*interpolatedTime));
            view.setLayoutParams(rLParams);
    }
}
```

Now add a view in layout itself with height set to 0.

find that view and call this:

```
view.startAnimation(new HeightAnimation(view,oldHight,i*10));
```

Comment: For LayoutParams in 'old+(new-old)*t'  t is not an int to perform '*' action

Comment: check my edit. I made a mistake use interpolatedTime instead of t.

Comment: How can i give HeightAnimation with out having any constructor in view.startAnimation(new HeightAnimation(view,oldHight,i*10));